# After upgrade to 20.04: "Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search"

Tags: 20.04, search

I just upgraded from 18.04LTS to 20.04, and now my desktop search function for applications always says "Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search".  The search for other types of files is not working either.

I do not think I have any gnome-shell-extensions either, as another post has suggested as a problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: For me, I had this problem with Unity - I tried to describe my solution for Unity here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289564/ubuntu-20-04-unity-no-applications-in-start-menu-after-upgrading-from-18-04/1289565 , also paradoxically switching to another GUI (e.g. Gnome) actually also "solved" the issue.

Comment: If you find a way to keep using Unity without this bug, let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.  Somehow during the upgrade I got switched to Unity.  Switching back to gnome solved the problem.

Comment: Can you describe steps you did to achieve this result?

Comment: @jave.web there's a button before logging in that opens a menu including Unity and Gnome, pick one before logging in.