# Ubuntu 20.04 Unity No applications in "start" menu after upgrading from 18.04

Tags: 18.04, unity, 20.04, launcher, applications-lens

So yesterday I've upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04, firstly I had to finish up with a partial upgrade that the software updater suggested, then it asked me to remove all the unused packages so I did, then I've ran it one more time to ***be sure ALL the software is up to date***, it seemed at first glance it went well.

Today I found out there are no applications in the "start" menu (when you click on the Ubuntu icon on the launcher, some may call it applications lens) - I only got a message "Sorry, there is nothing that matches your search" application menu gone too with same message.

I did search a bit but I found a similar problem only for gnome caused by gnome-tweaks tool, but I am using Unity, but in the end...

## ...I found the solution - see steps in my answer :)

Answer (score 9):

Since I know I did use a tweak tool, although not for gnome, but for Unity - `unity-tweak-tool` I did try to make a similar approach and it worked :) Also I did want to **keep my Unity**, not replace it with another OS GUI (which also works btw - switching to  e.g. Gnome BEFORE you login).

### but first ... (Step 1)

First I found out that I don't have a GUI way to launch terminal, luckily, there is a shortcut

**Open your terminal:** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>

### Step 2: trying to run unity-tweak-tool

Try to run `unity-tweak-tool` from terminal if the graphical interface of `unity-tweak-tool` starts fine - **skip to step 3**

However, for me it yelled about missing packages, it seemed all to be related to `unity-lens-SOMETHING`, when I installed one, another popped out, so I just ended up installing all of the `unity-lens-*`, error could look like

`Error: schema com.canonical.Unity.ApplicationsLens not installed` - notice the pattern of this error and what I'm installing:

```
sudo apt install unity-lens-applications
sudo apt install unity-lens-music
sudo apt install unity-lens-video
sudo apt install unity-lens-files
sudo apt install unity-lens-photos
```

After this, run `unity-tweak-tool` from terminal again and it **should** start normally, if it does => **go to step 3**, if it does not, try to install any dependencies it requires - usually the package has a similar name as the required stuff in `com.canonical.Unity.SOMETHINGMISSING` something `unity-*`.

If you just write DONT ENTER YET! `sudo apt install unity-` to the terminal and hit `TAB` 2x, it will show you all `unity-*` packages - that is not THAT much of them, so you can search there for any missing stuff, similarly for other missing stuff.

### Step 3: reseting Unity tweaks

Now that you are in a working GUI of `unity-tweak-tool`, under the "Unity" category, open `Launcher` - write down all the settings you made there and hit the `Restore defaults` button, confirm any questions (you can set your settings back later) - do the same for all the tabs in the Unity category:

```
Unity -> Launcher -> Restore defaults
Unity -> Search -> Restore defaults
Unity -> Panel -> Restore defaults
Unity -> Switcher -> Restore defaults
Unity -> Additional -> Restore defaults
```

### Step 4: Restart your computer

After restarting, your start menu and the whole panel will be reset to its original position and everything (we've turned off all the tweaks), but application & search menu should now work normally.

### Step 5: Go to `unity-tweak-tool` again and adjust any settings back to your custom

Comment: Very nice find and well described. For me it was sufficient to **log out and in again** to get the applications back, no need to reboot.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you that way! However since you lose your session upon logout anyways - I would still recommend to reboot to make sure all dangling updates are finished and it didn't break anything (it happened to me once or twice in a different scenario, that everything was OK, untill ... reboot/restart :-D )