# Applications Missing from GNOME Launcher

Tags: 20.04, gnome, launcher, appmenu

I recently switched to GNOME after some KDE graphics driver shenanigans (Apps crashing, random segfaults, etc...)

After switching, I noticed that many apps were missing from the app launcher (Meta+A) - I checked `/usr/share/applications`, and sure enough, all my apps (`.desktop` files) were there.

I tried using the `alacarte` utility, but for some reason, it was buggy, slow and unresponsive (Half of the time the changes wouldn't save)

Is there any way to "re-register" the apps from `/usr/share/applications` (Or any other way to fix my app launcher)? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. It doesn't bother me because I use i3 almost all the time, rarely starting gnome. But I'm hoping someone offers you a solution because it's kinda bugging me.

Comment: Same here with a 20.04 install which is otherwise stable and `/usr/share/applications` well populated. A great hint would be already which launcher application it really is that is used from the top-most icon in a left-attached vertical gnome(unity?)-panel. Next step would be: where does it get its information from. Likely some file created/maintained with `update-desktop-database` which I ran already with no effect.

Comment: Actually for me it is the Unity-Desktop that I am debugging. Didn't really know which one it was. Just in case someone comes along a know something.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1289565/367444 worked for me